# Running if statement based on the results of multiple selections

Tags: php, mysql, select, social-media-like

this is probably going to require something very basic but I can't find an answer to do this in the way I want it to work.  What I have is a mysql table of articles and a table of favourites where if you like an article the information is logged.  So I need to select all of the articles that I like from one table and then all of the articles from another and display them all as a feed, which I have done.  The part I need help with is saying, if I like one of the posts, do not display the like button (Alternatively if I haven't yet liked it, show the button).  Can anyone please point me in the right direction with this? Here's the code I have but it only shows the last one I Liked:

```
<?php
$check_like_sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type = 'Like' && poster = '$yourid'";
$check_like_res = mysqli_query($con, $check_like_sql) or die (mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
    while($likes = mysqli_fetch_array($check_like_res)){
        $yourlike = $likes['media'];
    }
}
?>
<?php
$get_posts_sql = "SELECT posts.*, members.username, members.avatar, fans.connection FROM posts LEFT JOIN members ON members.id = posts.poster LEFT JOIN fans ON fans.fan = '$yourid' WHERE posts.poster = fans.connection ORDER BY date DESC";
$get_posts_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_posts_sql) or die (mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
    while($posts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_posts_res)){
        $postid = $posts['id'];
        etc
        etc


        if($yourlike == $postid){
            $likethis = "<a href=\"php/unlike.php?poster=$yourid&post=$postid\">Unlike</a> . ";
        }
        else if($posttype == "Like"){
            $likethis = "";
        }
        else{
            $likethis = "<a href=\"php/like.php?poster=$yourid&lat=$yourlat&lon=$yourlon&like=$postid&user=$postusername\">Like</a> . ";
        }

        $post .= "";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Could you add the code to the question?

Comment: Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statements and what you've already tried.

Comment: Sorry, Here's the edit with code

Comment: This would still be much easier if we had your database layout.

Comment: All I want to do is create an array of the media I like and then check it against the results of the $get_posts so that I can either display a like or unlike button, I guess like on twitter or facebook

Answer (score 1):

You can left outer join from your articles table to your liked_articles table.

```
select a.*, 
       case when la.liked_article_id is null then 'Not Liked Yet' else 'Already Liked' as LikedStatus 
from   articles a
left outer join liked_articles la
on     a.id = la.article_id
and    @userId = la.user_id;
```

This may not be syntactically correct for MYSQL but you get the gist.